# Rogue menus in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I keep getting the issue with VS2019 where when selecting a menu item, the menu moves to the top left of the screen and doesn't disappear. The rest of the application carries on working but this menu is still responsive, and cannot be dismissed.

[image]

I'm on a very underpowered machine so I can't tell if that's a factor, or if this is a known bug. Can anyone help? It obscures other menus and I keep having to re-open VS!

Comment: Are you running any Extensions? Are you running the latest version of VS?

Comment: It was only installed a few weeks ago so it might not have the very latest update, but pretty much